# Checking function with given signature then compile differently

Tags: c++, templates, macros

In a templated class, can we check a member function's signature *and* define different compilation behaviors for different subclasses? To be more specific, consider the following simple example:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    // ingore all other functions

    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(a);
    }
};
```

This should just work fine with the `T1` class:

```
class T1 {
    T1(int a) {
        // implememntation
    }

    // ingore all other functions
};

// Foo<T1> would just work
```

However, it will fail the compilation with `T2` because `Foo`'s `do_something` function is clearly implemented to call `T`'s constructor with one argument only:

```
class T2 {
    T2(int a, int b) {
        // implememntation
    }

    // ingore all other functions
};

// Foo<T2> would fail to compile
```

So the question is, can we rework on `Foo` to let it work for both `T1` and `T2`, in the way that, for `T1` and classes whose constructor takes one `int` argument, it will compile with a default implementation, whereas for `T2` and classes whose constructors are different, it will compile with a virtual function and enforce subclass to implement it with `override`. Somewhat like below:

```
Template <typename T>
class Foo {
    // ingore all other functions

    /* if T's signature takes one int input only
     * compile like the below
     */
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int x) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(x);
    }

    /* if T's signature is different
     * compile like the below and let the subclass implement it
     */
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int x) = 0;

}
```

Is this possible without using any 3rd-party library? It's acceptable if we have to use macros/preprocessors.

It is also acceptable if there must be one function `do_something` there but for the case of mismatched signature, it just raises runtime exception, something like:

```
Template <typename T>
class Foo {
    // ingore all other functions

    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int x) {
        /* if T's signature takes one int input only
         * compile like the below
         */
        // return std::make_shared<T>(x);
        /* if T's signature is different
         * compile like the below and let the subclass implement it
         */
        // std::throws...
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for `do_something` to be virtual?

Comment: Yes, because the subclasses may want to override it in the application; and other functions of `Foo` may need to call the overriden `do_something` too.

Comment: It is not possible in C++ to have two class methods with the same signature, and SFINAE won't help. What would be possible is for `Foo`, itself, to inherit from a specialized class based on `T` whose specialization will implement the appropriate `do_something` alternative. This would be a pile of code, but it's possible, and the same thing needs to be done for each `do_something` overload. That's the most that can be done here.

Comment: Why not simply make `Foo::do_something()` be a variadic template so it can take any number of constructor parameters?

Comment: Because it has to be virtual, see above.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in that case, can't `do_something()` be overloaded, or use `if constexpr`, using SFINAE based on `std::is_invocable`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the insights. So, is it still impossible by using preprocessors to guide it so there is always "one" function with same signature there, but just under different #if branches?

Comment: Well, if it's not invocable, the stated intention is for the function to be abstract. Perhaps a runtime exception would be a compromise.

Comment: Preprocessor stuff happens way, way before things like function signatures are examined. By the time the C++ compiler figures out what the various signatures are, preprocessing is just a faint memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and Sam, throwing a runtime exception is also acceptable if must not be a pure virtual function without any implementation. Could you elaborate the idea there?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. I've updated the question to allow throwing runtime exception instead of pure virtual function.

Comment: Then an `if constexpr`-based approach should work, as was mentioned earlier. That would be the simplest solution, for C++17. Before C++17 it would be a lot more work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sounds good. Could you elaborate it? I think that can be the answer. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: We're talking about some fairly advanced C++ techniques. Instead of cobbling together random code fragments, it will be far more meaningful to invest some quality time [on a good textbook on advanced C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) and get the full picture, not to mention useful information on all the other modern C++ features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, we need class template specialization here. Not even C++20 `requires`-clauses can be applied to `virtual` functions, so the only thing we can do is have the whole class change.

```
template<typename T> // using C++20 right now to avoid SFINAE madness
struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a) = 0;
};
template<std::constructible_from<int> T>
struct Foo<T> {
    virtual ~Foo() = default; // to demonstrate the issue of having to duplicate the rest of the class
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a) {
       return std::make_shared<T>(a);
    }
};
```

If there is a lot of stuff in `Foo`, you can avoid duplicating it with a heap of upfront cost by moving `do_something` to its own class.

```
namespace detail { // this class should not be touched by users
    template<typename T>
    struct FooDoSomething {
        virtual ~FooDoSomething() = default;
        virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a) = 0;
    };
    template<std::constructible_from<int> T>
    struct FooDoSomething<T> {
        virtual ~FooDoSomething() = default;
        virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a);
    };
}
template<typename T>
struct Foo : detail::FooDoSomething<T> {
    // other stuff, not duplicated
    // just an example
    virtual int foo(int a) = 0;
};
namespace detail {
    template<std::constructible_from<int> T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> FooDoSomething<T>::do_something(int a) {
        Foo<T> &thiz = *static_cast<Foo<T>*>(this); // if you need "Foo things" in this default implementation, then FooDoSomething is *definitely* unsafe to expose to users!
        return std::make_shared<T>(thiz.foo(a));
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrS4AOUlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEINqkAA6oQoTmtHaOLu7RsfF0vv5BTqHhkcaYpgkMBMzEBEnOrpwehcV0peUEWYEhYRFGZRVVKbVdza05eREAlEaoDsTIHFI6AMx%2ByI5YANSa8zZotDNRBEIb2JoyAIILSyuY65tOmE4kAJ6Hx2entMy3QlHMM6tYZXhWOsAOy6VYAenBqwICDwQlWy2YQnhQgQk1Y6FWtFQBFWoWhk2QCEwmOCD1WDhExAOp1WdOhdyiqgImA2NgIDyiVg%2BVwAKs9afShARiA5TKsAGKoVAAEVQDFQtxhfmAIP0gvp9IAbngKg42KsAH5S2XyxWYZXqCCja4yv6YKjMBysAgbdUnTWanV6g3C9AgECo8okgD6e2IbP582wf1QIaE5stwAgflxzBtGztMjdL01mmBMpzGoZTiZzBZbL9Ae2wtFxWC7BDVGIirZqcOqyjR2LtbFuJNcoVSth6kjHfz7s92t1BH1QON0sHiZHyYz8ztWEdztd80nU9W3tnvoI/sDCGD6DDIrH0dj8eXKpT9FW6aLHvp%2BcLu5en5eLNLzKspsHJcu8tydgKJy9uKJqrCA9oAqwAYDmaw4qjeMYTrm9KQqsOLEsQqzCg4VBUKQWI4n8DhMngLAsug2F0rhCiUmmtCrJg4gfEyrLFoec6rKmqw0KgT5pmuWZvr%2B35vDyXw/Fc/zMICaqMSWZYVpsVYoHQ0FmA2mBNi2ThtvQHZdmp2lBsQobhhhkqLqhForhhAboHGCZoVaQnpqpxaaia9k6AAbMqABetqrAAVMK5a0SGLDCmygWbF2UWHBAypCKMboQlCeBUKsDyTFimAkus2jaLBSYHJVgnsVl9pbi6gkAXcVhlGYdDkTCVgOaaQ7OSqgnwlFm5%2BIQmCsA8UUUrQQjMFQVxEBx4gxCIBIUlSQhgGAamajZs7EOx2lOMwADWhnWSSGGZbCYUAHQiRA6Y5TJ750r%2Bpxfa8UEin2qwMHgbVwf1pk7phoJqUJz0%2BTaqBamExB4GsE6rIdUzscwuU/dJ7p6asJzEKqWHFj5xPkVqbAOEBe50kTybk8A5FCVTjiYDa8HlMm3PjAe1OYBAbM0xmoIgoW30Fm%2BBN2G14igylNgM%2BOUNk8%2BsPPr5CNIyjVxoxjx0vtFL441LPYngG12XnZmzK7e7n3l5jOa/DiPEMjqNi7h7mYPC2K4mgpaAlcADuhBog4uJZft9IGydFsgGdl3xueNkMbbxMZcw5HPa9b55mbZxS%2B9P7aIsOyXNcNjmLWmAfJB2mxCKddOBVwWoFyxDliQbJshAje1x8beTAQ5EMwium4iFvN%2BR96MWpjeGR1XbIVdoDMQDo2gr5sL7Ew93M7zYa/kVvR978AD3C3rmyr1vOWVVJhdCWdfjWrPmpAyDBzvZq2loMvXuu8YoPQdp5IaVoACsa4bB30fpAmwtAt753pLLHi8stC/yFAnABU9b7AOQKAjyD4oEwLgdoTQCCkGPxLgWKQ4wkJSEgfIVwsh5CoGkLAvQBgiKTGmHrMunB5AEGkHIUY4xzogGCjIB6nBgTBXmNwGQABObQkDgRuGUW4YKKhpDcBYaI9h0h5BCBADIUgIi2HjDgLAGAiAdJB3YGQCgEBA5RGDuEYAQh3hRFRDiPggIWTUkoMEQxpBgh%2BHKA8aQQjSCB1uPQAA8rQaaYSsBnXUOwNJuoihmERqYthnhxBFEjrMOQ5B6BTTCawPAwQu7EAeHYLAYSRTAxifQvgdBGAsCyTwTpggRASDCUoSIqh1AoAMAYFQtTTGQHGB3Lq81pAAFo/SZi0NwvQ2hyn1EWZYawvQaieGsEMdo4ROBpDiIsw5yh1oZFoKc3IHQLm7JKN0So9hqjKFeY0d5jyRgvPeTcwFgw/BtCeec8YCYpgzC4Aw6QzDSCsPKRwqQ4htHLOCtwVYwBkDIFWJlUUtBzo2ggLgQgJAKrzAuasNBHiqXaBtFw/QehhGGPEaQSR8x5gPW5Xy/lArdFSH0aQJwIBIFuF5comQbgZDcEgco4EwIZCcE4JApFYTUUmLMRY9lpAbH2JHlESO5BKBuI8Z0EkFLzn9O6WwDgfT%2BAEGEGISQhSQ5dyiO0%2BFTCDGFNRYkyOxrcSoEKui4KmLsW4vxYShwxLSV0qcQy0YbKrHjGJMwLA4RrRCpFWK7gnAHrSOUZwZRkClGVS0W4dVyKjFSG1eYyxYiJEgHmMoh6bgy7BQVTIYE3BtCcBVbwRh8w/UouMbqtNQrtBjrram5tpA3ZxAsNwIAA%3D%3D)

To convert this down from C++20, replace the concept-based specialization with old-type branching:

```
// e.g. for the simple solution
template<typename T, bool = std::is_constructible_v<T, int>>
struct Foo { // false case
    // etc.
};
template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, true> { // true case
    // etc.
};
// or do this to FooDoSomething if you choose to use that
```

A runtime error is much easier, at least in C++17 and up, since you can just use a `if constexpr` to avoid compiling the problematic code

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> do_something(int a) {
        if constexpr(std::is_constructible_v<T, int>) return std::make_shared<T>(a);
        else throw std::logic_error("unimplemented Foo<T>::do_something");
    }
};
```

Comment: This is super complete and easy to follow. Thanks a lot for the help!